# block php page in public view

Tags: php, .htaccess

block php page in public view. but still able to use by other page.

hi, I'm working on a website that has ajax live search(search.php) on it, search.php calls in from another php page to search in database, it works just fine, the problem is search.php can be typed in url and display all data from database. I tried googling it, still don't have clear idea how to solve it. I've read that it can be done in .htaccess, also by changing permission... I just want to be enlightened how to properly fix the problem. thanks

Comment: Please take a few minutes to review the answers submitted to your question and 'Accept' the answer that is the best solution to your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

how I would do it would be by adding another $_POST variable to the form.. something like the following..

```
$.post('search.php', {search: 'search term', secret: 'ajax'}, function(r){
  $(insert).html(r)
})
```

and then on the post page..

```
if(isset($_POST['secret']) && $_POST['secret'] == 'ajax'){
  // do your submitting..
} else {
  // display some kind of error message since the secret post wasnt found
}
```

Comment: wow, answered so fast... i'll try this one. BIG THANKS TO YOU.

Answer (score 0):

Try this make sure to place it at the top of the search.php page :D

```
if(basename(__FILE__) == basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) send_404();

function send_404()
{

    header('HTTP/1.x 404 Not Found');

    print '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">'."\n".

    '<html><head>'."\n".

    '<title>404 Not Found</title>'."\n".

    '</head><body>'."\n".

    '<h1>Not Found</h1>'."\n".

    '<p>The requested URL '.

    str_replace(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?'), '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).

    ' was not found on this server.</p>'."\n".

    '</body></html>'."\n";

    exit;
}
```

Comment: wow, thank you for introducing me to PHP_SELF, I'm still learning PHP, but this will disable the search on other page?.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in the first lines of search.php file

```
/***************DO NOT ALLOW DIRECT ACCESS************************************/
if ( (strpos( strtolower( $_SERVER[ 'SCRIPT_NAME' ] ), strtolower( basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ) !== FALSE ) { // NOT FALSE if the script's file name is found in the URL
  header( 'HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden' );
  die( '<h2>Forbidden! Access to this page is forbidden.</h2>' );
}
/*****************************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by having non-landing PHP pages live outside the public html folder, often in a /php or /lib folder just above the public html folder.  This kind of assumes that all your landing pages include some form of bootstrap that sets up your include path to include the /php folder.

Another easy-ish solution is to have your landing php files set a value or constant, and have your includes refuse to execute if the value isn't set - This way you cannot execute the php file directly.

**index.php**

```
<?php
define(VALID_REQUEST, 1);
include "include.php"
...
```

**include.php**

```
<?php
if (!defined(VALID_REQUEST)) { exit; }
...
```